# corruption of the heap

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, heap-corruption

I have one function dealing with image. In that function, i am trying to find several particular ellipses. The code is working if i call it individually in a separate project, but in the whole project, it crashed when it returns.

I used many vectors in the processing to store some information during the process.

The error information:

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in KinectBridgeWithOpenCVBasics-D2D.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in     KinectBridgeWithOpenCVBasics-D2D.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while KinectBridgeWithOpenCVBasics-D2D.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

could any one tell me where is wrong to cause this crash. More weird is it is working in the separate project.

The code is a little long, but it is really noting, just looking for several particular ellipses with some pattern.

Thank you.

```
int FindNao(Mat* pImg, double* x, double* y)
{
// Fail if pointer is invalid
if (!pImg) 
{
    return 2;
}

// Fail if Mat contains no data
if (pImg->empty()) 
{
    return 3;
}
//*x = 0; *y = 0;

Mat localMat = *pImg;       // save a local copy of the image
cvtColor(~localMat, localMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);         // Convert to gray image
threshold(localMat, localMat, 165, 255, THRESH_BINARY);     // Convert into black-white image

Mat elementOpen = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5,5), Point(-1,-1));
morphologyEx(localMat, localMat, MORPH_OPEN, elementOpen, Point(-1,-1), 1);

// Find all the contours in the blak-white image
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(localMat.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
localMat.release();
// Calculate the area of each contour
vector<double> areas; int num = contours.size();
/* If no contours are found, return S_OK */
if(num < 1)
    return 1;

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    areas.push_back(contourArea(contours[i]));
}


// First round of selection 
// The area is small, and they are like a ellipse and around the middle in X direction and at the upper part of the image
vector<RotatedRect> selected_ellipses;      // store the fitted ellipse fitted to the potential contour
vector<double> selected_areas;              // store the contour area of the potential contour
int imgX = localMat.cols; int imgY = localMat.rows;     // get the demension of the image

for(int i=0; i < num - 1; i++)
{
    if(areas[i] < 350 && areas[i] > 10)
    {
        // fit an ellipse 
        RotatedRect ellipse1 = fitEllipse(Mat(contours[i]));

        // it is a reasonable ellipse, and the area should be close to the 
        double length1 = ellipse1.size.height;
        double length2 = ellipse1.size.width;

        if( abs(1 - length1/length2) <= 0.8 &&
            abs(1 - areas[i] / (CV_PI * length1 * length2 / 4) ) <= 0.2 )
        {
            selected_ellipses.push_back(ellipse1);
            selected_areas.push_back(areas[i]);
        }
    }
}

/************ Second round of selection **************/

// Calculate each ellipse's dimension
vector<double> diff_dimension;
vector<double> ave_dimention;
/* If no contours are found, return S_OK */
if(selected_ellipses.size() < 1)
    return 1;

for(int i = 0; i < selected_ellipses.size(); i++)
{
    double difference = abs(1 - selected_ellipses[i].size.height / selected_ellipses[i].size.width);
    diff_dimension.push_back(difference);

    double average = (selected_ellipses[i].size.height + selected_ellipses[i].size.width) / 2;
    ave_dimention.push_back(average);
}

vector<vector<int>> eyematches;
vector<vector<int>> cammatches;
// go over all the ellipses to find the matches with close area and dimension.
for(int i = 0; i < selected_ellipses.size() - 1; i++)
{
    for(int j = i+1; j < selected_ellipses.size(); j++)
    {
        // looking for the eyes
        if(diff_dimension[i] < 0.05 && diff_dimension[j] < 0.05)
        {
            double diff_area = abs( 1 - selected_areas[i] / selected_areas[j] );
            if (diff_area < 0.05)
            {
                double diff_y = abs(selected_ellipses[i].center.y - selected_ellipses[j].center.y);
                if(diff_y < 10)
                {
                    vector<int> match1;
                    match1.push_back(i); match1.push_back(j);
                    eyematches.push_back(match1);
                }
            }
        }

        // looking for the cameras
        double diff_x = abs(selected_ellipses[i].center.x - selected_ellipses[j].center.x);
        if (diff_x < 10)
        {
            vector<int> match2;
            match2.push_back(i);  match2.push_back(j);
            cammatches.push_back(match2);
        }
    }
}


/* Last check */
int num_eyes = eyematches.size();
int num_cams = cammatches.size();

if(num_eyes == 0 || num_cams == 0)
    return 1;

// Calculate the vector between two eyes and the center
vector<Point> vector_eyes;  vector<Point> center_eyes;
vector<vector<int>>::iterator  ite = eyematches.begin();
while(ite < eyematches.end())
{
    Point point;
    point.x = selected_ellipses[(*ite)[0]].center.x - selected_ellipses[(*ite)[1]].center.x;
    point.y = selected_ellipses[(*ite)[0]].center.y - selected_ellipses[(*ite)[1]].center.y;
    vector_eyes.push_back(point);

    point.x = (selected_ellipses[(*ite)[0]].center.x + selected_ellipses[(*ite)[1]].center.x)/2;
    point.y = (selected_ellipses[(*ite)[0]].center.y + selected_ellipses[(*ite)[1]].center.y)/2;
    center_eyes.push_back(point);

    ite++;
}

// Calculate the vector between two cameras and the center
vector<Point> vector_cams;  vector<Point> center_cams;
ite = cammatches.begin();
while(ite < cammatches.end())
{
    Point point;
    point.x = selected_ellipses[(*ite)[0]].center.x - selected_ellipses[(*ite)[1]].center.x;
    point.y = selected_ellipses[(*ite)[0]].center.y - selected_ellipses[(*ite)[1]].center.y;
    vector_cams.push_back(point);

    point.x = (selected_ellipses[(*ite)[0]].center.x + selected_ellipses[(*ite)[1]].center.x)/2;
    point.y = (selected_ellipses[(*ite)[0]].center.y + selected_ellipses[(*ite)[1]].center.y)/2;
    center_cams.push_back(point);

    ite++;
}


// Match the eyes and cameras, by calculating the center distances and intersection angle
vector<vector<int>> matches_eye_cam;
vector<vector<double>> matches_parameters;
for(int i = 0; i < num_eyes; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < num_cams; j++)
    {
        vector<int> temp1;
        vector<double> temp2;

        // calculate the distances
        double distance = sqrt( double( (center_eyes[i].x - center_cams[j].x)^2 + (center_eyes[i].y - center_cams[j].y)^2 ) );

        // calculate the cosine intersection angle
        double cosAngle = vector_eyes[i].x * vector_cams[j].x + vector_eyes[i].y * vector_cams[j].y;

        // store everything
        temp1.push_back(i);     temp1.push_back(j);
        temp2.push_back(distance);      temp2.push_back(cosAngle);

        matches_eye_cam.push_back(temp1);
        matches_parameters.push_back(temp2);
    }
}

// go over to find the minimum
int min_dis = 0; int min_angle = 0;
vector<vector<double>>::iterator ite_para = matches_parameters.begin();
/* If no contours are found, return S_OK */
if(matches_parameters.size() < 1)
    return 1;

for(int i = 1; i < matches_parameters.size(); i++)
{
    if( (*(ite_para+min_dis))[0] > (*(ite_para+i))[0] )
        min_dis = i;

    if( (*(ite_para+min_angle))[1] > (*(ite_para+i))[1] )
        min_angle = i;
}

// get the best match of eyes and cameras 's index
int eyes_index, cams_index;
vector<vector<int>>::iterator ite_match_eye_cam = matches_eye_cam.begin();
if(min_dis == min_angle)
{
    // perfect match
    eyes_index = (*(ite_match_eye_cam + min_dis))[0];
    cams_index = (*(ite_match_eye_cam + min_dis))[1];
}
else
{
    // tried to fuse them and find a better sulotion, but didnot work out, so 
    // go with the min_dis
    eyes_index = (*(ite_match_eye_cam + min_dis))[0];
    cams_index = (*(ite_match_eye_cam + min_dis))[1];
}

vector<vector<int>>::iterator ite_eyes = eyematches.begin();
vector<vector<int>>::iterator ite_cams = cammatches.begin(); 

// draw the eyes
ellipse(*pImg, selected_ellipses[(*(ite_eyes+eyes_index))[0]], Scalar(0, 255, 255), 2, 8);
ellipse(*pImg, selected_ellipses[(*(ite_eyes+eyes_index))[1]], Scalar(0, 255, 255), 2, 8);

// draw the camera
ellipse(*pImg, selected_ellipses[(*(ite_cams+cams_index))[0]], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8);
ellipse(*pImg, selected_ellipses[(*(ite_cams+cams_index))[1]], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8);

imshow("show", *pImg);
// find the upper camera
int m1 = (*(ite_cams+cams_index))[0];
int m2 = (*(ite_cams+cams_index))[1];

int upper;
if(selected_ellipses[m1].center.y < selected_ellipses[m2].center.y)
    upper = m1;
else
    upper = m2;

*x = selected_ellipses[upper].center.x;
*y = selected_ellipses[upper].center.y;

return 1;
}

int main()
{
Mat imO = imread("Capture.PNG");
double x, y;

FindNao(&imO, &x, &y);

cout<<x<<"      "<<y<<endl;

cvWaitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: Make sure that all your dlls were compiled for your same compiler version and you are not using debug dlls in a release application or release dlls in a debug application. All of these will cause random looking heap corruption.

Comment: As the code you show does not give too much information, I suggest that when your exception triggers click the "Retry" button, that will open the debugger, and in its stacktrace you will find references to functions that were being called when the problem was detected. From there you can start investigating

Comment: @DWilches, Thanks for replying. I tried that it shows more information:                                 Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData).     How interesting thing is, this function is working in a individual project,  but in the whole project it doesnot.   If you can help me more, that will be great. Thanks.

Comment: That exception is something internal to one of the C++ libraries (instead of corrupting your memory, they do an assertion so you can find easier the problem). What you need to check is in that stacktrace what is your last function called (I mean, the last function whose name you recognize as your own), that is the offending function. Normally with that kind of exception is not the topmost you see in the stacktrace, but the 3rd or 4th (just check the names).

Comment: @DWilches, the problem arouse when the function return. I have one function findContours() which is an opencv function. this function will store the contours in <vector<vector<Point>>. I tried to clean the contours, same problem happened. so I think the problem is the memory collected by the findContours(). So it should be a heap corruption problem by this.

Comment: @drescherjm, thanks for your responses. I further checked the code, and the dll. for those I can understand they are all in debug mode. the problem happens when the function return, and further test shows when i try to clear a vector<vector<Point>> variable, same problem happened. So I think the problem is just the memory collected by this variable. Any more thing you can think up that can be helpful for this problem? Thanks